# Using the Struts Validator, can I check if all fields are empty?

Tags: java, validation, struts-1, struts-validation

I'm rewriting parts of an old project to make use of the [struts 1 validator framework](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/faqs/validator.html).

I've adapted the validation rules on each individual field, with a regular expression that can be reused in other forms, such as:

```
        <field property="idNumber" depends="mask">
            <msg name="mask" key="error.formating.idnumber" />
            <arg position="0" value="SearchForm.idNumber" />
            <var>
                <var-name>mask</var-name>
                <var-value>${maskIdNumber}</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>
```

There's one validation left to implement: I need to make sure that the user's has filled *any* of the fields before submitting. Looking at the FAQ I saw that there are conditions like `validwhen` that can be used to validate fields against each other, but if I'm not mistaken they have to be attached to one of the form's field.

If I write this:

```
        <field property="idNumber" depends="validwhen">
            <msg name="mask" key="error.form.empty" />
            <arg position="0" value="SearchForm.idNumber" />
            <var>
                <var-name>test</var-name>
                <var-value>(idNumber != null) or (packageNumber != null)</var-value>

            </var>
        </field>
```

The test will only be tried if the field "idNumber" is not empty, right ? The FAQ states that

> Any field that isn't 'required' will skip other validations if the
>   field is null or has a length of zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried using `validwhen`, but it was introduced in Stuts 1.2, and I'm on 1.1 so I get the error *No ValidatorAction called validwhen found for field idNumber*.

I could use `requiredif` but it may use the worst syntax I have ever seen.

Instead, I followed the technique from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20086863/113305, and used both the `Struts validator framework` and the `validate()` method:

```
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ActionErrors errors = super.validate(mapping, request);

    if (idNumber.length() < 1 && packageNumber .length() < 1) {
        errors.add("emptyForm",
                new ActionError("error.form.empty", "emptyForm"));
    }

    return errors;
```